# Exclude certain folders in Vite and Rollup with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vite, rollup

I am using `Vite` to bundle my `Vue.js` app, I have `@vitejs/plugin-vue` and `@rollup/plugin-typescript` installed.

I would like `Vite` to skip bundling certain folders inside my `src` folder:

```
src > assets  
...  
src > skins  
src > skins > skin1  
**src > skins > skin2**
```

I have tried the `exclude` option in the `vue` and `typescript` plugins, neither work for me. Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
    const config = {
      mode: process.env.MODE,
      root: PACKAGE_ROOT,
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '/@/': join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'src') + '/',
        },
      },
      plugins: [vue({
        exclude: ['**skin2'],
      })],
      base: '',
      server: {
        fs: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
      build: {
        sourcemap: true,
        target: `chrome${chrome}`,
        outDir: 'dist',
        assetsDir: '.',
    
        rollupOptions: {
          input: join(PACKAGE_ROOT, 'index.html'),
          external: [
            ...builtinModules.flatMap(p => [p, `node:${p}`]),
          ],
          plugins: [
            typescript({
              exclude: ['**/skin2'],
            }),
          ],      
        },
    
      }
    };
```

I also tried RegExp which also didn't work, what I've missed? Thank you!